# VueJS & PHP Api

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, fetch-api, sqlsrv

I am 'new' to PHP so this question probably has a very obvious answer, so Ill apologize in advance.

Situation:

I am running a VueJS project, running it with npm run serve and then deploying it with npm run build to a laragon apache server with PHP 7 on it.

That all works great.

I am now moving from using our C# API which we have hosted and you hit it as a URL. To a PHP Api, this API is just set up with a straight connection to SQL using sqlsrv_connect. This is also working when I host it on apache/laragon in its own folder and hitting it on its own URL extension.

But what I was wanting to do ( and not sure if this is possible )
Is in my VueJS project put the .php files in a data folder and hit them like this fetch("src\data\GetSQLData.php?table=Clients&columns=top%2010ClientID"")

Is this possible, or should I rather have them hosted separately and use the URL method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy,
Vuejs is a front-end framework.What it means is, When you do `npm run build` then it will create bunch of `js` and `html/css/image` files on the server.Then you require a web server to server these files.

When you hit the url on your web-browser then all these files will download into 
 the web-browser and then execute over there.This is how front-end framework works in a nutshell.

PHP is a back-end scripting language.Which means it require back-end php engine to run and execute the code logic.So it has nothing to do with vuejs that is running on your web-browser.

Best possible way to connect these 2 applications is via API.You should request data from a php API which is running on back-end web server.

`fetch('http://localhost/GetSQLData.php?table=Clients&columns=top%2010ClientID')`